# java scanner while loop wont stop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Im a first year CS student and I am working on an assignment but I ran into this while loop that won't stop...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ass1{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i=0;

    try{
        File myfile = new File ("./ages.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myfile);

        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("ages.txt contains " + i + " lines");
        scanner.close();
    }catch(IOException e){}
}
}
```

and the ages.txt file looks like the following (They are meant to be all in separate lines but somehow I can only show  them in a line here :(  )

200
201
202
203
205
205
207
208
210
213
214
217
218
219
219
221
225
226
227
227
231
232
238
238
240
309
313
314

I am trying to read all the lines from the text file and at the end print how many lines it contains.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You never advance the cursor. And you'll want to use `hasNextLine()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to advance your scanner by calling `scanner.next();`

If you were counting lines, it would be better to use `scanner.hasNextLine()` and `scanner.nextLine()` respectively.

The way you have it written, `scanner.hastNext()` will always evaluate to true as the scanner has never actually left it's initial position, so there will always be a `hasNext()`

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.
but how would I go about adding scanner.next(); ?

Comment: NP, good luck in your studies. And you can add it by typing it :p. Just think where you would want to advance where your scanner was pointing. HINT: Think of where you are counting the lines.

Comment: @redFIVE **+1** for not spoon feeding the OP

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not calling nextInt() method inside the while loop which means the Scanner never advances to the next token.